# Viber-bot узнать откуда пришел пользователь

Tags: php, viber-api

Можно ли определить, откуда пришел пользователь в вайбер бота? Либо передавать какой-то параметр?

Мне это нужно для того, чтобы после нажатия на START, отправлять пользователям разные сообщения в зависимости от того, откуда пришел пользователь, или в зависимости с каким параметром (меткой) он зашел в чат-бота.

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось все просто:

```
viber://pa?chatURI=<URl>&context=parametr
```

Может кому пригодиться :)